# Mysql join multiple foreign key

Tags: mysql, join

I have a PHP/MySQL application but the previous developer has done this in the database

```
tbl_cat columns:

cat_id | cat_name

tbl_products columns have cat_id assigned:

category_1 | category_2 | category_3
```

What I need to do is assign the `tbl_cat.cat_name` to (`category_1`, `category_2` etc...)

I know the `as` here is wrong but just to demonstrate it must be something similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_products 
LEFT JOIN tbl_cat 
ON category_1=cat_id AS cat_1 
AND category_2=cat_id AS cat_2 
AND category_3=cat_id AS cat_3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A normal `select` syntax when using join is:

```
SELECT        
      table_alias_1.column_1 AS column_alias_1,
      table_alias_2.column_2 AS column_alias_2,
      table_alias_3.column_3 AS column_alias_3
FROM  table_1 AS table_alias_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 AS table_alias_2 
     ON table_alias_1.column_1 = table_alias_2.column_2
LEFT JOIN table_3 AS table_alias_3
     ON table_alias_2.column_3 = table_alias_3.column_3;
```

It does not matter if table_1 is the same as table_2 as long as they have different aliases you can join a table to itself.

You cannot declare assignments within select statements**. An `=` sign within a select statement will be interpreted as a comparison operator not an assignment operator.

** There is an exception to this rule - a non standard extension MySQL provides which is not part of ANSI-SQL, but this is used to assign values variables which will be used outside of the select not within it; the assignment operator is `:=` not `=`; this is basically a replacement for the ANSI SQL standard `SELECT ... INTO ...`.

Comment: thanks that looks a bit complicated, in the end I just picked the first column category as part of the initial statement and then ran seperate statements on the rest

Comment: It's a bit slower when you select & join data using PHP. SQL is optimized for selecting, joining, filtering, sorting, grouping etc.. But if it works for you for now that's fine, more time to learn SQL.